# Jmeter beanshell Encounter ";"

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to execute beanshell script in jmeter for a URL parameter value. I have the following:

```
${__BeanShell(vars.get("query").replaceAll(" ","%20"))}
```

The jmeter console outputs this:

```
Caused by: bsh.ParseException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``vars.get("query").replaceAll(" ";'' Encountered ";" at line 1, column 33.
```

I can't figure out what the problem is as the character there is a `,` not a `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing something ridiculous. Encoding an URL is not only about escaping spaces, looking into [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) documentation you will need to handle:

- All non-Latin non-alphanumeric characters
- All characters apart from `.`, `-`, `*`, and `_`

Which might be very tricky.

So you basically have 2 options:

- Use JavaScript [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function via JMeter's [__javaScript function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript)  like:

  ```
  ${__javaScript(encodeURIComponent("${query}"),)}
  ```
- Or use aforementioned URLEncoder from [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

  ```
  ${__groovy(URLEncoder.encode(vars.get('query')\, 'UTF-8').replaceAll('\\\+'\,'%20'),)}
  ```

Performance-wise in cases of high loads Groovy is preferred option, check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code in [Beanshell PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) or [BeanShell PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) in order to replace single space character to `'%20'`:

```
String myString = vars.get("query");
String new_var = myString.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
vars.put("updated_value", new_var);
```

You can further use `'updated_value'` variable having space replaced by `'%20'` in next requests.

Please refer to the [JMeter Knowledge Base](https://www.redline13.com/blog/kb/) for more information on JMeter elements.

Answer (score 1):

See [JMetrer's functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) tutorial, you need to escape every comma:

> If a function parameter contains a comma, then be sure to escape this with "\", otherwise JMeter will treat it as a parameter delimiter.

In your case

```
  ${__BeanShell(vars.get("query").replaceAll(" "\,"%20"))}
```

Also consider using `__groovy` function instead of `__BeanShell` for better performance.